# jQuery dialog not firing in Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog

I currently have it set up so that a dialog box should display if an AJAX post is successful.  The AJAX post is successful (the alert below is firing), but the dialog box is not displaying.  I can't figure out why.  Here's my markup:

```
<a data-eventid="@item.EventId" id="raffle-@item.EventId" class="raffle-charity-button" href="#"><img src="~/Images/Raffle.png" alt="Raffle" title="Pick a winner!"/></a>

<div id="raffle-event-dialog">
    <p class="dialogDisplayWinner">
    </p>
</div>
```

...And here's my script:

```
$(".raffle-charity-button").click(function() {
            charityEventId = $(this).data("eventid");
            //charityEventId = parseInt($(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]);
            var url = "@Url.Action("Raffle", "DonationEvent")";
            var postData = {
                id: charityEventId
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: postData,
                datatype: "json",
                success:
                    function(data) {
                        if (data != "") {
                            if (data.Success == "false") {
                                window.location = "../Error";
                            } else {
                                var originalVerbiage = "The winner of the raffle is... "
                                $(".dialogDisplayWinner").empty();
                                $(".dialogDisplayWinner").append(originalVerbiage + "test");

                                $("#raffle-event-dialog").dialog({
                                        modal: true,
                                        autoOpen: false,
                                        buttons: {
                                            "OK": function() {
                                                $("#raffle-event-dialog").dialog("close");
                                            }
                                        },
                                        resizable: false
                                    }
                                );
                                alert(data.Success);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                error:
                    function(jqxhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("An error occurred: error Code(" + jqxhr.status + ") message: " + jqxhr.responseText);
                    }
            });
        });
```

Is it something obvious I'm overlooking?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the dialog with the option `autoOpen` set to `false`, so the dialog will not open automatically (check the documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen)). Change this value to `true` or call to open the dialog later:

```
$("#raffle-event-dialog").dialog('open');
```

Comment: Ack! My interpretation of the `autoOpen` option was incorrect.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your code the autoOpen attribute is false. Set it to "true" to automatically open the dialog.

```
$("#raffle-event-dialog").dialog({
         modal: true,
         autoOpen: true,
         buttons: {
         "OK": function() {
             $("#raffle-event-dialog").dialog("close");
            }
          },
          resizable: false
        }
 );
```